# Возвращаемое значение метода может быть частью класса? C++

Tags: c++, классы, методы

Предположим, имеется следующий класс "TestClass" с публичным методом "getStructure" и приватной структурой "testStructure":

```
class TestClass{
public:
    AnyStructure getStructure(){
        return this->testStructure
    }
private:
    AnyStructure testStructure;
}
```

Если я буду менять значения полей структуры, полученной от getStructure(), то будут ли меняться значения полей структуры, что в классе?

Comment: Как вы собрались получать что-то от `getStructure()`, если тип возвращаемого значения у `getStructure()` - `void`???

Comment: Упс, да, сейчас подправлю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    AnyStructure& getStructure()
    {
        return this->testStructure;
    }
private:
    AnyStructure testStructure;
};
```

Вот в таком варианте - да.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете методом getStructure возвращать ссылку на вашу структуру, как в ответе @Harry, или вернуть указатель, а в месте применения разыменовывать его

```
AnyStructure * getStructure()
{
     return &this->testStructure;
}
```